# How to blacklist Splunk events from specific host and sourcetype

Tags: splunk, blacklist

I have already asked this question on the Splunk website but didn't get any reply. I hope Stack Overflow users can help me.

I want to blacklist events with the `debug` keyword in them, from host `host1` and sourcetype `source::type`. Can anyone help me with this? I know I can blacklist events either from host or sourcetype but not from both.

Here is the configuration I have tried:

```
# Props.conf
[host::host1]
index=new-index 
TRANSFORMS-set= setnull


#transforms.conf
[setnull]
REGEX = .*\s+Debug\s+.*
DEST_KEY = queue
FORMAT = nullQueue
```

This works best just for `host1` but I want other sourcetypes from `host1` with `Debug` to be whitelisted.

Answer (score 1):

Your event most probably contains an identifier of either the `host` or the `sourcetype`. If that is the case, you need to factor that into your regex and do the property match against the other property (i.e. if `host1` is contained in the event's text, than you filter against the `sourcetype` in `props.conf`)

If I remember correctly there is a (more complicated) way to chain queues where you put all events from `host1` that contain `debug` into a `temporary` queue and then only send events with both `host` and `sourcetype` to the `nullQueue`.